# How do I send multiple excel files to multiple groups in Outlook?

Tags: python, email, email-attachments

I am trying to generate 5 email which have- 5 groups of recipient and each group receives a couple of excel files.
I want to automate an email where specific files goes to specific groups. But fail to attach multiple files in the code. My code breaks down when I try to attach multiple files.

Is there any solution?

Here is the list with code:-

```
#email list
recipient_list= [a,b,c,d,e]
a="ww@aeg.com, ageg@egag,com, ..........."
b= "age@ege.com , ..............."
.
.

#file list

all_file=[af,bf,cf,df,ef]

af =[AL_sum,AL_time,AL_transfer]
bf= [.............
.
.

AL_sum= str(pathlib.Path(folder_directory+"/Daily report*.xlsx").absolute())
.
.
.
```

```
import win32com.client as client
import pathlib


def outlook_send_mail(recipient,all_file):
    outlook=client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    message=outlook.CreateItem(0)
    message.To=recipient
    message.CC=CC_recipient
    message.Subject="Daily reports" +date
    message.Attachments.Add(all_file)
    message.Body="Kindly find the attachments"
    message.Save()
    message.Display(True)
    #message.Send()
    
ee=0


while True and ee<5:
    for ff in range(3): #3 files
        outlook_send_mail(recipient_list[ee],all_file[1][1] )
        print(name[ee]+"  send!")        
        ff+=1
        
    ee+=1    



print("Emails send, Task complete!")
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying various loops got my answer.

```
def outlook_send_mail(recipient,vendor_file, team_file):
    outlook=client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    message=outlook.CreateItem(0)
    message.To=recipient
    message.CC=CC_recipient
    message.Subject="Daily Report " + date
    if ee<5:
        for i in range(ee*3,ee*3+3):
            message.Attachments.Add(vendor_file[i])
    else :
        for ii in range(0,6):
            message.Attachments.Add(team_file[ii]) 
            
    message.Body="Kindly find the attached daily reports" 
    message.Save()
    message.Display(True)
    #message.Send()
    
    
ee=0
while True and ee<6:
    outlook_send_mail(recipient_list[ee], all_daily_reports, team_file)
    print(name[ee] +" email send!")

    ee+=1
```